# Custom Field Type - Data is not being saved

Tags: custom-fields, database

I'm creating a custom field type. But the data isn't being saved to the database. There are several values that are being combined into a string, divided by a pipe character.

I've checked the `save()` function, and it returns the string that I want to have saved in the database. But when I check the database, the field is empty, or has only one character.

Example string: `http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xyz/xyz/filename.jpg|55|170|541|541|1:1|260|260`

But actually, it doesn't matter what string it is. It never gets saved. Or in some cases only the first letter.

What could I be doing wrong?

EDIT: the save function itself

```
function save($data)
    {
        $content = FALSE;
        $custom = array();

        foreach($this->custom_fields as $key)
        {
            $val = ee()->input->post($key.'_field_id_'.$this->field_id);
            $custom[] = $val;

            if (strlen($val)>0)
            {
                $content = TRUE;
            }
        }

        $toReturn = "";

        if ($content)
        {
            $toReturn = utf8_encode(implode('|', $custom));
        }

        return $toReturn;

    }
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code? Also the save() function looks for an array, not a string...

Comment: I've added the save function above. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved.

The fieldtype was using array data. But I rewrote it to save the data as a simple string. Makes things easier if you want it to work with some add-ons like Publisher.

But I forgot to remove `var $has_array_data = TRUE;` from the class. Simply removing it, or setting it to `FALSE` solved the issue.